# The Stackexchange Elections Statistics for Stack Exchange Participation are wrong

Tags: support, election

I have entered the SciFi.stackexchange elections, and just looked at the [Election statistics](http://elections.stackexchange.com/) page.  However, under my entry, it shows my site participation as being part of only 2 SE sites, with a total reputation of 431:
[image]

However, I have far more rep than that just on the sci-fi site, and over 20k across all sites:
[image]

Is this a problem with my account, are the statistics wrong, or am I just somehow horribly mis-reading this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That page currently uses the 1.0 API to pull information about the candidates, which uses a now-deprecated association GUID to pull up your associated accounts. Not all of your accounts are associated with that GUID, for one reason or another (a potential explanation being that since associations are no longer mapped that way, that information is no longer updated).

However, pulling your associations with the new 2.0 API will return the correct list of accounts based on your network account ID. I'm in the process of updating the Election Statistics page to use the new API, and in light of this causing a misrepresentation of your activity, I'll try to finish that up as soon as possible.

Comment: I've seen this problem with other users, even on established accounts; the 1.0 API doesn't return all associated accounts any more. So it's not so much "deprecated" as "completely broken"

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Hmm, that seems bad. All the more reason to upgrade, I guess.